# How to rearrange data from excel?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have data in a spreadsheet which I have to upload in sql. The problem is that this data is quite crude. I need to rearrange the sheets in the excel file in terms of their relation with eachother. The first sheet has master data a colum of this sheet is to be linked to data in the other sheet. All I have is a sheet in which data is embedded. The relation between data is displayed using an expander button. Please tell me how I can rearrange this data fast? I think this can be done by running sql queries or ssis package but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS package with multiple Source components (inside Data Flow) to access each sheet.

Once you can see both sources, you can sort all key columns using a sort component and then use a Merge Join to combine the two sets of data together

Comment: But one sheet contains data for two tables in a cellular hieracrhy. How do I segregate different data from one cell?

Comment: You will need to embed the same logic you would use to determine the two sets of data in ssis.  How do you know when one set of data ends and the other starts?  Maybe posting an example would help